# How To Create 'Transparent' or 'Undetectable' Symbolic Links With NTFS?

Tags: windows, ntfs

I'm currently using three 'cloud' services (Google Drive, Dropbox and SkyDrive).  However, they are not very customizable; I've been unable to set all three services to sync the same local folder.  And, because different services have different space limits, I want them to have a seperate local folder.

For example, I have the follow:

- C:\Users\me\Google Docs\
- C:\Users\me\SkyDrive\
- C:\Users\me\Dropbox\

I have some 'super important' documents that I keep in another location

- D:\Documents\IMPORTANT

Because these are 'important' I want them sync'd to all three services as soon as I create something in that folder.

I've used **MKLINK** in an attempt to do this:

```
MKLINK [[/D] | [/H] | [/J]] Link Target
```

Inside of each three local folders, I've used MKLINK to create a link to **D:\Documents\IMPORTANT**  -  It appears to work.  Locally I see the folder, and can navigate to it.  I only have a single copy of each file - everything is great.

*EXCEPT*

Google Drive doesn't sync it.

It 'knows' that it is not a real directory and it treats it differently!  This appears to be a known issue:
http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/vImyhTG7qWs%5B1-25-false%5D
http://blog.redhed.org/2012/04/use-existing-folder-for-google-drive.html

My understand of a symbolic link was that it was meant for exactly this situation.  I want my applications to be unaware that the link is symbolic.  I want them to simply see a folder with files in it.  The OS, obviously, should handle this correctly 'behind the scenes'...but I would expect this to be transparent to the applications I'm running.

I'm starting to ramble, but, Is there anything I can use, besides MKLINK that will do, essentially, the same thing, but in a way that is 'transparent'?

Comment: Based on the research I have done it does not appear you can.  You won't make it transparent because the OS still needs to know the symbolic link exists.  I use GoodSync to sync folders outside of those directories for my own use.  There will be three copies + original no matter what  ( at least in the cloud ) so I just create 4 copies.

Comment: Any reason you insist on symbolic links? Have you tried junction points (`mklink /j`) which can be used to refer to existing folders? It's possible Google Drive also ignores these, but they're different, so it may as well consider them for syncing.

Comment: Have you created a Junction or a link?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean hardlinks?  Use `fsutil hardlink create`

```
C:\Users\ultrasawblade>fsutil hardlink create 
Usage : fsutil hardlink create <new filename> <existing filename>    
Eg : fsutil hardlink create c:\foo.txt c:\bar.txt
```

Comment: I believe a hardlink would work; but then I would need to create a hardlink for each individual file, right?  I'm trying to link a directory.

Comment: last time i checkd folder junctions were synced by dropbox, treating them as normal folders